# R can't find some packages when running via crontab

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, cron

I am having problems when trying to run my R script using `Rscript` via `crontab`.

The following command works fine when running in the command line

```
Rscript /var/www/html/sent/sentiment/code/parse.r
```

But the following line inside `crontab`

```
*/5 * * * * Rscript /var/www/html/sent/sentiment/code/parse.r > /var/www/html/sent/sentiment/code/backup.log 2>&1
```

Will return the following error in the log

```
Error in library(twitteR) : there is no package called 'twitteR'
Execution halted
```

Why is it possible that Rscript won't be able to find the packages when running using cron?
How can I make crontab 'see' my R packages.

Any tip much appreciated.

Comment: I would start by running `which Rscript` as yourself and as a crontab, see if you are both using the same install.

Comment: Thanks, I will make the test. In order to run it as crontab is there a command to run as crontab or I just add it to my script and save the output to a log file?

Comment: There might be better ways, but I would just schedule `* * * * * which Rscript > /tmp/Rscript.path`.

Comment: You are right, for some reason they were in different locations! Make it an answer so I can mark it right. Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the problem might be that you and your crontab are using a different R install.

To check if it is the case, run `which Rscript` as yourself and as crontab.

If they are different (which I suspect), you could use the full path to the appropriate `Rscript` when you are calling it from crontab. A more permanent solution would require setting environment variables.

Comment: How do you run `which Rscript` as crontab and not as yourself?

Comment: @HillarySanders. Add `* * * * * which Rscript > /tmp/abc` to your crontab. Wait a minute, then `cat /tmp/abc`.

Answer (score 1):

It will most likely be your `.libPath()` setting -- which is why I instrument to the Debian/Ubuntu package to use a system-wide, rather than per-user, setting.

To check, run as you as well as from the same crontab

```
 print(.libPaths())
 print(installed.packages())
```

The difference should become clear.  I think I answered an almost identical question here before.